# bitcoin-cli testnet : Could not connect to the server 127.0.0.1:8332

Tags: port, tcp, amazon-ec2, ubuntu-20.04, bitcoin

I've installed bitcoin-cli from [here](https://bitcoin.org/bin/bitcoin-core-22.0/bitcoin-22.0-x86_64-linux-gnu.tar.gz)

I run the bitcoin core on Ubuntu 20.04 (AWS EC2).

mac-os also experiences similar problems.

[Ubuntu 20.04 screen capture for the error messages](https://i.stack.imgur.com/05mMi.jpg)

The commands I've ran :

Installation on Linux (Ubuntu 20.04)
• Download and extract the package

```
$ wget https://bitcoin.org/bin/bitcoin-core-22.0/bitcoin-22.0-x86_64-linux-gnu.tar.gz

$ tar -xzf bitcoin-22.0-x86_64-linux-gnu.tar.gz
```

• Installation

```
$ cd bitcoin-22.0
$ sudo install -m 0755 -o root -g root -t /usr/local/bin bitcoin-22.0/bin/*
```

• Start a node

```
$ bitcoind -testnet -daemon
```

Check blockchain status

```
$ bitcoin-cli -testnet getblockchaininfo
```

After I started a node, and i try to run some bitcoin-cli-testnet commands , the following error comes :

```
error: timeout on transient error: Could not connect to the server 127.0.0.1:8332
```

Comment: Please add the exact commands you've ran

Comment: Please edit your question with additional information instead of adding it as a comment, as comments could get removed.

Comment: Please use the appropriate code tags to drastically improve the readability of your question and eliminate formatting errors. Also please add the output of the commands, as most people are not good enough at mind-reading.

Comment: Check if the service is running on the port by executing `sudo netstat -tulpn`

Answer (score 1):

I started using bitcoin core 2 years ago. I recommend you first start by opening the application version, not the daemon, just to make sure you have finished the installation correctly:

```
$ bitcoin-qt
```

Then, wait for the blockchain to sync. That could take a couple of days.

Alternatively, you could do this:

```
$ bitcoind -testnet -daemon & tail -f ~/.bitcoin/debug.log
```

However, it is always recommended to build the software from the source code. You can find a very thorough guide here (plus you get the bonus to learning how to operate your node using TOR network, and how to build your lightning node. If you dont want to do that, just ignore those parts of the tutorial)

https://stopanddecrypt.medium.com/running-bitcoin-lightning-nodes-over-the-tor-network-2021-edition-489180297d5

Comment: Not helpful. QT does not launch an obvious daemon and doubt it launches one at all.

Comment: Come on! Did you even read what I wrote? I said launch QT only to figure out if your conf file is correctly configured, and then on the second line I give u a line that prints the log of launching the bitcoin daemon in testnet.